# Is this a P trap or a S trap?

Tags: plumbing

We bought a new dishwasher and it still leaves the dishes smelling like rotten eggs.
After some research I came across information that a ptrap is required to stop the smell from drain. The pipe connection behind the dishwasher looks like this. Pls can someone tell me whether this can be classified as a p trap or it is still a s trap[image]

Comment: Looks like a S trap, but just need to get of the black elbows.  Rotten egg smell might be coming from your water itself.  The heat of the dishwasher making it worst than from the cold water.

Comment: Is the end of that flexible hose from the washer just loosely poked into the end of the vertical standpipe, or is it sealed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

That's clearly an S-trap - or rather, a P-trap (white) converted to being an S-trap by the arrangement of black pipe fittings after it.

You'll need to lower the P-trap so the outlet is in line with (technically 1/4" per foot higher, so about 1/16" inch higher at a guess here) the pipe entering the wall, and change to an elbow coming out to the side to meet it, as opposed to the "up-and-over" that's making an S.

You might want to look into "hub-saver" or "socket-saver" tools to make re-using the fitting in the wall practical, rather than needing to tear the wall open to replace that fitting.

Comment: I can't understand your 2nd para. 1/16" wouldn't make that much difference, would it?

Comment: All "horizontal" Drain lines should (*i.e.* it's code) actually slope downhill to the drain. Looks like about 3", so 1/16 of an inch is the required 1/4" per foot or 2% slope.